# a way to check if data frame contains a smaller data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to data frames so I apologize if the question is obvious ,Assume I have a data frame that looks like that:

```
  1 2 3
  4 5 6
  7 8 9
```

and  I would like to check if it contains the following data frame:

```
  5 6
  8 9
```

is there any build in function in pandas.dataframe that do it?

Comment: don't know if this is the most efficient way but the following works: `(np.intersect1d(df, df1) == df1.values.ravel()).all() == True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposed two dataframes have the same relative columns and index (I assume so as they are dataframe not just values array), here is a quick solution (not the most elegant or efficient) where you compare two dataframes after `combine_first`:

> DataFrame.combine_first(other)
>
> Combine two DataFrame objects and
>   default to non-null values in frame calling the method. Result index
>   columns will be the union of the respective indexes and columns

Example:

```
df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

df1
   a  b
1  4  5
2  7  8

all(df1.combine_first(df) == df.combine_first(df1))
True
```

or, if you want to check df1 (smaller) is in df (you know their size already):

```
all(df == df1.combine_first(df))
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much, saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @MaximDunavicher, not a prob, glad it helps :)